# How to Count Consecutive Enteries for Users in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Given the table with the following columns:

- UserId int,
- DateEntered DateTime

And the data:

```
1  | 2016-02-24
1  | 2016-02-23
1  | 2016-02-22
1  | 2016-02-20
2  | 2016-02-24
2  | 2016-02-14
3  | 2016-02-23
3  | 2016-02-22
3  | 2016-02-21
2  | 2016-01-30
2  | 2016-01-29
2  | 2016-01-28
2  | 2016-01-27
2  | 2016-01-26
2  | 2016-01-25
```

I would like to return the latest streak of entries for each user and actually for a specific user from today.

**Case 1**

- Today = 2016-02-24
- userid = 1
- Return value = 3  // User missed Day 21 so streak is from 22-24

**Case 2**

- Today = 2016-02-24
- userid = 2
- Return value = 1  // Even though user has a longer streak from 1/25 – 1/30, it is not his latest streak

**Case 3**

- Today = 2016-02-24
- userid = 3
- Return value = 0  // User missed today. Therefore, he has no consecutive days counting today

Any ideas on how this can be done in T-SQL?

**Update 1**:

Based on the response, I've modified the example query given as follows: Yet, the value returned in the second column is always only either 1 or 0, even though the data shows that there are more consecutive days present.

```
select 
    a.UserId,
    sum(case when dayseq = '2016-02-01' then 1 else 0 end)
from
   (select 
        t.*,
        dateadd(day, 1 - row_number() over (partition by UserId order by DateCreated), DateCreated) as dayseq
   from 
       fa.User_Journal t) a
where 
    DateCreated <= '2016-02-01'
group by 
   a.UserId;
```

**Update 2**

The following query illustrates the problem further. The solution provided below almost resolves this.

In this query, I illustrate what "should" happen given the @EndDate values. By un-commenting the desires assignment to @EndDate, you can see that the query does not return the desired result according to the cases provided.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

```
DECLARE @Temp TABLE
(
    UserId nvarchar(128),
    DateCreated Date
)

INSERT INTO @TEMP (UserId, DateCreated) values ('uid123', '2016-01-19');
INSERT INTO @TEMP (UserId, DateCreated) values ('uid123', '2016-01-24');
INSERT INTO @TEMP (UserId, DateCreated) values ('uid123', '2016-01-28');
INSERT INTO @TEMP (UserId, DateCreated) values ('uid123', '2016-01-29');
INSERT INTO @TEMP (UserId, DateCreated) values ('uid123', '2016-02-01');
INSERT INTO @TEMP (UserId, DateCreated) values ('uid123', '2016-02-02');
INSERT INTO @TEMP (UserId, DateCreated) values ('uid123', '2016-02-03');
INSERT INTO @TEMP (UserId, DateCreated) values ('uid123', '2016-02-07');
INSERT INTO @TEMP (UserId, DateCreated) values ('uid123', '2016-01-19');


DECLARE @EndDate Date
SET @EndDate = '2016-02-03' -- Should return 5, as they are 5 consecutive days since @EndDate
--SET @EndDate = '2016-02-02' -- Should return 4, as they are 4 consecutive days since @EndDate
--SET @EndDate = '2016-02-19' -- Should return 1, as they are 4 consecutive days since @EndDate
--SET @EndDate = '2016-02-18' -- Should return 0, as they are 0 consecutive days since @EndDate


SELECT a.UserId,
    SUM(CASE WHEN dayseq <= @EndDate then 1 else 0 end) -1 as FitStreak
from (select t.*,
                dateadd(day,
                        1 - row_number() over (partition by UserId order by DateCreated),
                        DateCreated) as dayseq
        from @Temp t
        ) a
where DateCreated <= @EndDate
group by a.UserId;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the following does what you want:

```
select t.UserId,
       sum(case when dayseq = '2014-02-24' then 1 else 0 end)
from (select t.*,
             dateadd(day,
                     row_number() over (partition by UserId order by DateEntered desc) - 1,
                     DateEntered) as dayseq
      from t
     ) t
where DateEntered <= '2014-02-24'
group by t.UserId;
```

This subtracts a sequential number from each date, starting with 0.  It then compares the result to the "current date" -- and voila, the value is the "current date" for the initial sequence.

The logic in the `case` statement can also be in the `where`.  However, the results will then filter out users with no days.

Note two important assumptions:

- There is no time component on the date
- There are no duplicate dates

Both of these can be easily handled, but the resulting query is a bit more complicated.

EDIT:

With a time component, truncate the value:

```
select t.UserId,
       sum(case when dayseq = '2014-02-24' then 1 else 0 end)
from (select t.*,
             dateadd(day,
                     row_number() over (partition by UserId order by DateEntered desc) - 1,
                     cast(DateEntered as date)) as dayseq
      from t
     ) t
where DateEntered < dateadd(day, 1, '2014-02-24')
group by t.UserId;
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7d/2966) is a SQL Fiddle illustrating the fixed code.

Comment: Gordon, there is a time component. How would the query be different. I probably should have included that - was trying to make the question simple. Thanks for the assistance.

Comment: So, I think I'm doing something wrong here. I only get back mostly 0, and sometimes 1 for the sum column.   I'll edit my question with my modified query based on yours.

Comment: Ok, figured it out, the second line should be:  SUM(CASE WHEN dayseq <= '2016-02-01' then 1 else 0 end).   Thanks for the help Gordon.

Comment: Gordon, I was wrong, it still is not working correctly. Please see my Update 2 in the original question, perhaps you can help me work through that. I would greatly appreciate it. I hope that update is clearer. Thank you.